# Mapped network drives using GPO falsely showing disconnected

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, network-share, mappeddrive

Network drives are mapped using GPO, however some of the drives are showing up as "Disconnected Network Drive X:" even though they are connected. The icon shows them as connected and if you click on the drive it connects to the share. Its just the wording of the drive. it causes a lot of problems becuase users report that they can't access their drives, even though they could if they tried. How can I make them show the normal text?

Comment: I've got a similar problem, except my users never look at the icon, so they never complain.

Answer (score 2):

Fixes for this very annoying issue:

1) Change the autodisconnect timeout

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameter­s (svr)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Service\lanmanworkstation\parameters (workstation)
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684

2) If you're running symantec AV 10 ... follow this MSDN article
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932463

3) Have the logon script disconnect and reconnect the network drive (easy .vbs) at logon

One of those should fix you. If not - let me know and I'll follow up.